# SUM() with the Max Column and Fixed Column Value if exists

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to get the sum of these records, the condition is keep status=Processing if it exists in the records and the Latest UploadedOn with its corresponding UploadedBy

```
[RecordDate] [FileCount] [Status] [UploadedBy] [UploadedOn]
 11/30/2017      1       On-queue   tester1     12/21/2020 01:24:40.000000000 PM
 12/31/2017      3       Success    tester1     12/23/2020 10:26:45.000000000 AM
 12/31/2017      3       Processing tester2     12/25/2020 10:26:45.000000000 AM
```

Currently I only get the sum(RecordDate) with the Max(UploadedOn) using this query

```
SELECT REPORTING_DATE, sum(FILE_COUNT), max(UPLOADED_ON)
from IRREGULAR_FILES_UPLOADS 
group by REPORTING_DATE
```

And my wanted output is with

```
[RecordDate] [FileCount] [Status] [UploadedBy] [UploadedOn]
 11/30/2017      1       On-queue   tester1     12/21/2020 01:24:40.000000000 PM
 12/31/2017      6       Processing tester2     12/25/2020 10:26:45.000000000 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Windows functions` this way :

```
WITH data
AS (
    SELECT RecordDate, FileCount, STATUS, UploadedBy, UploadedOn, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY RecordDate ORDER BY RecordDate) AS RN, 
    SUM(FileCount) OVER (PARTITION BY RecordDate) AS SUM_FILECOUNT, 
    MAX(UploadedOn) OVER (PARTITION BY RecordDate) AS MAX_UPLOADEDON
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
    )
SELECT RecordDate,SUM_FILECOUNT AS FileCount,STATUS,UploadedBy,
       MAX_UPLOADEDON AS UploadedOn 
FROM data WHERE RN = 1
```